# How to fix this crack in the outside corner of my ceiling

Tags: repair, ceiling, paint, crack, bedroom

This ceiling corner in my bedroom is sagging down. I saw that it’s tearing up from one end and looks like something was put in there to make the edges curved and is getting loose from there.
What is it and can it be fixed by DIY?

[image: fall ceiling in room]

Answer (score 2):

That's probably a vinyl bull nose corner that's installed right after the drywall. They are supposed to be secured with screws or nails but some have been installed with adhesive and that just doesn't hold up. Check to see if it's easy to push back in place and then use some small brads or finishing nails to hold it in place. Touch up with some spackle or white toothpaste.(lol)

Comment: Thnx @jack. Is there any video you can point me to?

Comment: @Jack   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zSuiGUqVd4    There are many videos out there, just google "install bull nose corners on drywall".   You'll see that there are many different types of corners.